# Wordpress get permalink of a first page of a specific page template

Tags: wordpress, templates, permalinks

I wonder if it is possible in Wordpress to get the permalink
of a first page of a specific page template.

For example, I have a couple of custom page templates.

In my index page I have to anchors that one should load the first page of default (text) page template and the second should load the services template for example.

Is it possible to achieve this in Wordpress?

If yes, what is the solution?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: wordpress has a load [template function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_template) - although i dont understand what you want exactly.

Comment: Could you please make your requirement more specific/clear

Comment: For example I have 4 pages that use the same page template. All those pages have different permalinks. My goal is to get the permalink of the first page of that template. Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any WordPress functions to do this (that I know of) but you can write your own query with [$wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). If I had a template with a filename of "template-faq.php" and wanted to get the permalink of the first page that used this template it would look like this:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
/* Get post IDs of all pages using "template-faq.php" */
$faq_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `post_id` FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE `meta_key` ='_wp_page_template' AND `meta_value` = 'template-faq.php' ", ARRAY_A);
/* Get permalink using post ID of first page in the results */
$faq_permalink = get_permalink($faq_pages[0]['post_id']);
?>
```